# The state does not change React

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, react-props

I have a form with radio buttons. This is the screen as it is interpreted by the React add-in in the browser.
[image]

I am wondering why the value `value` is empty and why there is no `onChange` function that changes state. In the state I have the variable `checked: false` as click on the button, the state should change, which would cause the change of styles of buttons.

This is my component responsible for creating the radio button. Here, it passes props from the component that creates the form. And in this component also keep the state responsible for `checked`.

```
class RadioButton extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      checked: !checked,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      value,
      backgroundColor,
      backgroundColorChecked,
      borderColor,
      height,
      width,
      ...otherProps
    } = this.props;
    const { checked } = this.state;
    return (
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          value={value}
          checked={checked}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: checked ? `${backgroundColorChecked}` : `${backgroundColor}`,
            borderColor: `${borderColor}`,
            height: `${height}`,
            width: `${width}`,
          }}
          className="Test__questions-radio"
          {...otherProps}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    );
  }
}



RadioButton.propTypes = {
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  borderColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  height: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  width: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

RadioButton.defaultProps = {
  backgroundColor: '',
};
```

This component passes to

```
const QuestionsAnswerForm = ({
  onSubmit,
  initialValues,
}) => (
  <FinalForm
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FinalField name="rate">
          {({ input }) => (
            <FormGroup>
              <Radio
                value="more-unaware"
                type="radio"
                backgroundColorChecked="#94657e"
                backgroundColor="#fff9fc"
                borderColor="#94657e"
                height="2.375rem"
                width="2.375rem"
                {...input}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          )}
        </FinalField>
        <FinalField name="rate">
          {({ input }) => (
            <FormGroup>
              <Radio
                value="unaware"
                type="radio"
                backgroundColorChecked="#94657e"
                backgroundColor="#fff9fc"
                borderColor="#94657e"
                height="2.0625rem"
                width="2.0625rem"
                {...input}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          )}
        </FinalField>

      </Form>
    )}
  />
);

QuestionsAnswerForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
};

QuestionsAnswerForm.defaultProps = {
  onSubmit: () => {},
};
```

Why is not value passed? Why does the onChange function not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't uncheck a radio button by clicking on it. You can use a name to group them together so that only one in the group can be checked at a time. Or you can force them truthy or falsy as I have in the example I provided below.

Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l32z8qxnv9) example for you.

Comment: @KeyleRichardson Your solution is ok, but what then, for example, do I have 10 radio buttons? Can I create a 10 element array? Or maybe you've come across a more optimal solution somewhere?

Comment: @Elder Why would something other than an array be optimal? Arrays are basic objects. A 10 item array is super small... run this in a console `arr.forEach((el) => {console.log(`${el} @ ${Date.now()}`)` and you'll see it iterates through 10 items, creates 10 functional execution contexts, 10 template literals and logs the results to the console all in under 2 milliseconds. Seems fine to me.